# Why cant a web service return a dictionary?

Tags: html, web-services, asmx

I have an ASMX web service that returns a dictionary but get an error each time it is posting

> type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[BL.Customer, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary

Comment: An error. Mind sharing it with us, or should we guess? When asking a question, it is best to provide all relevant information - including code, what the error is and how it is triggered.

Comment: Sorry, it says, type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[BL.Customer, BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary

Comment: FYI, ASMX web services are a legacy technology that should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to post the error you are actually recieving but as it goes....... IDictionaries are not supported by web services by default so it is best to serialise the dictionary you are parsing. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164135.aspx)  article shows how to serialise the IDictionary

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could serialize the dictionary, SOAP has no representation of a dictionary-type structure. The client would have no idea that the service was sending a dictionary.