# How to return JObject as json object from WebServices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, json.net

I have a huge dataset of Jobject type created in following format

```
{
    "key_1": {"id":"1", "name":"some1", ....},
    "key_2": {"id":"", "name":"some2", .....}
}
```

I have created such object structure using following code:

```
JObject res = new JObject();
JObject jo = new JObject();
jo.Add("id", "1");
jo.Add("name", "some1");
res.Add("key_1", jo);
```

and so on;

I have a webservice method which has return type object and attributes as

```
[WebMethod][ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

how to return this data as object in ajax request. I tried

```
res.ToObject<(object)>()   //added curely braces around object because of html object tag
```

but it returns empty array collection at client side, but my expectation is get result as mentioned above (a proper object). How should i return res to get desired json output

Comment: IMHO JObject is not an ideal return type for a web service, even though under the hood it's a Dictionary more or less, it makes it difficult for tooling (swagger etc) to auto document the api and may add additional complexity for consumers. You could use JObject internally but return as a Dictionary<string, string> perhaps. Just a thought.

Comment: IDictionary is not serializable as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841497/6480144

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot. Sorry for the confusion. @Mayur-Patil.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited - thanks Brian**
There is a difference between things you **CAN** do and things you **SHOULD** do...

The right way to return your JObjects is up to you... create real objects that represent them... create key / value pairs that can be serialized...

What you don't want to do is just write the JSON out to the response...  however since that's literally what your asking... here is how you would do it.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetObject()
{
    string json = GetJsonFromDatabase();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
}
```

Note that your method has to return void and you are writing your json straight out to the response stream.  Super dirty... super ugly... please don't do this.  You'll also have to manually turn it into an object on the js side.

Comment: Except he's not using Web API, he's using ASMX.

Comment: Solved the problem by serializing dictionary<string, customClass> &  later using newtonsoft seralizeobject method.